# Как считать файл с флеш-накопителя после неправильного извлечения?

Tags: windows, файловая-система, fat32

Имел неаккуратность неправильно извлечь флэшку из компа — теперь появились сложности с чтением и сохранением информации на моём накопительном устройстве. Меня интересует считывание отдельного файла (остальные файлы на этом накопителе ненужная мелочёвка, но с ними та же самая ерунда).

Хотелось бы, по возможности, вернуть доступ к файлу каким-нибудь ручным методом (на край готов рассмотреть и другие варианты).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если есть какие-то важные данные, то вытащи их с помощью [r.saver](http://rlab.ru/tools/rsaver.html), потом можно прогнать проверку раздела через `chkdsk e: /f /r`, где "e" - буква флэшки. Если не поможет - просто отформатируй заново.